# Aggregating categories in categorical variables when insignificant in regression

Tags: regression, categorical-data, model-selection

I would like to run a regression model with all categorical variables. Since my response is count data, I am using a negative binomial regression model.

I would like to retain as many categories as possible so if a variable is deemed insignificant, instead of dropping the category my approach is to reclassify it with another category (inside the same variable ofcourse).

So for example If I have a model with:

y ~ Number of fruits eaten (dependent variable)

gender ~ (m,f)

age ~ (0-15, 16-64, 75+)

location ~ (London, Birmingham, Manchester, other)

I run a NBR and we find out Birmingham is insignificant with p = 0.2
I aggregate Birmingham with Manchester (manchester p value = 0.0000001) and this results in a p value of 0.001.
You can now say this segment is significant but my main questions are:

1. Is this approach statistically sound and if so, what should I look out for?
2. What would be the best category to aggregate with if there were dozens of segments. i.e. should i pick a significant variable and aggregate with variables which have a low p-value but not low enough to be called significant?
3. An idea I have is to calculate all the different combinations of segments and the model which results in the lowest AIC is good (but maybe not the best). Is this approach viable?